# How to make slide down menu to slide up?

Tags: javascript, html, css

It is my first time put css code, If you want more code,please ask me.
How to change the slide down action to a slide up action? I want to put the menu on the bottom of the page.
I have search a lot of documents and didn't find a  good solution.

Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $('#nav li').hover(function() {
  $('ul', this).slideDown(200);
  $(this).children('a:first').addClass("hov");
 }, function() {
  $('ul', this).slideUp(100);
  $(this).children('a:first').removeClass("hov");  
 });
});
```

```css
.wrap {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
/* @group core nav menu */

#nav {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #d5dce8;
    border-right: 1px solid #d5dce8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d5dce8;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    background: #edf3f7;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 0 1px;
}
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #818ba3;
    zoom: 1;
    border-left: 1px solid transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 0px 12px;
}
#nav li a:hover,
#nav li a.hov {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #d5dce8;
    border-right: 1px solid #d5dce8;
    color: #576482;
}
/* @group subnav */

#nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1px;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
#nav ul li {
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    text-align: left;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
}
#nav ul a {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 8px 5px;
    color: #666;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #797979;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#nav ul a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    background: transparent;
    color: #4e4e4e;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>DesignShack Sexy Magazine-Style Dropdown Menu</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all" />
</head>

<body>


<div class="wrap">
 <ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Homepage</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About the Mag</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Authors</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Write for Us?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Advertising</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Get in Touch</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Freebies</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">PSD</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">AI Vectors</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Patterns</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Icons</a></li>
   </ul>   
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HTML5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PHP MySQL</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ruby on Rails</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Web Tools</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Performance</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Browser Testing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CMS Plugins</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cheat Sheets</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Originals</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Website Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">User Interface</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Freelancing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recently I have come across such problems, lucily I found the key point.

You just need to add a simple line of code into the Css style sheet, to change the default direction of pop up menu, I think.

The line I added in your #nav.ul style means the bottom position of the pop up menu, that makes your menu pop up upwards.

Good luck with your further study.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $('#nav li').hover(function() {
  $('ul', this).slideDown(200);
  $(this).children('a:first').addClass("hov");
 }, function() {
  $('ul', this).slideUp(100);
  $(this).children('a:first').removeClass("hov");  
 });
});
```

```css
.wrap {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
/* @group core nav menu */

#nav {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #d5dce8;
    border-right: 1px solid #d5dce8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d5dce8;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    background: #edf3f7;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 0 1px;
}
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #818ba3;
    zoom: 1;
    border-left: 1px solid transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 0px 12px;
}
#nav li a:hover,
#nav li a.hov {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #d5dce8;
    border-right: 1px solid #d5dce8;
    color: #576482;
}
/* @group subnav */

#nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1px;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    ***bottom: 50;***
    list-style: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
#nav ul li {
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    text-align: left;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
}
#nav ul a {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 8px 5px;
    color: #666;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #797979;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#nav ul a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    background: transparent;
    color: #4e4e4e;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>DesignShack Sexy Magazine-Style Dropdown Menu</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all" />
</head>

<body>


<div class="wrap">
 <ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Homepage</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About the Mag</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Authors</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Write for Us?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Advertising</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Get in Touch</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Freebies</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">PSD</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">AI Vectors</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Patterns</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Icons</a></li>
   </ul>   
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HTML5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PHP MySQL</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ruby on Rails</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Web Tools</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Performance</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Browser Testing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CMS Plugins</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cheat Sheets</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Originals</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Website Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">User Interface</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Freelancing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/s0o3nqL6/2/) ?

I've changed the bottom value of `#nav ul` to `50px`